# running cross compiled binary on AllWinner device gives not found error

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, openwrt

I want to cross compile a C++ application for AllWinner board runing OpenWRT. I've found the [toolchain](https://github.com/wuweidong0107/allwinner-toolchain) and trying to build Hello world app using CMake as described in [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html). So I have allwinner.cmake file containing

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Also I have CMakeLists.txt with this contents:

```
project(hello)
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

I am building the app using this command:

```
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=allwinner.cmake
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release . && cmake --build build
```

After that i receive ***hello*** binary, copy it to the board in /tmp and trying to run it there as follows:

```
# cd /tmp
# ./hello
sh: ./hello: not found
```

I do not understand why i receive this error and what does it mean. Running **ldd hello** gives me:

```
# ldd hello
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7fb543b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7fb541b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
```

This output looks as something correct.

Could anybody explain me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used invalid toolchain. It was detected when I compared two ldd outputs. As I've wrote earlier my binary gives this:

```
# ldd hello
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7fb543b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7fb541b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x7fb5587000)
```

And ldd of system's ls gives this:

```
# ldd /bin/ls
    /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0x7f7b940000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f7b920000)
    libc.so => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0x7f7b940000)
```

As you can see the difference is in libc. My binary wants to use **ld-linux-aarch64** and ls binary use **ld-musl-aarch64**. I've downloaded aarch64-musl cross-compiler, built my binary using it and voila, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to run executables from `/tmp`.

You may check the mounted filesystems with the command `mount` and see `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec` attribute.

Comment: I also tried to place the binary in /bin with the same result